# Issue with AttributeError: partially initialized module 'charset_normalizer' has no attribute 'md__mypyc' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, tensorflow, attributeerror

I am trying to use TensorFlow on my M1 Macbook using VScode and I followed this guide (https://www.mrdbourke.com/setup-apple-m1-pro-and-m1-max-for-machine-learning-and-data-science/) in doing so. I know that the tutorial is using jupyter notebook but I need to run tensorflow inside VScode. Now, when I try to run this python script:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
print(f"TensorFlow version: {tf.__version__}")
```

I get `"AttributeError: partially initialized module 'charset_normalizer' has no attribute 'md__mypyc' (most likely due to a circular import)"`

I ran the script in VSCode inside the tensorflow-test folder that I had created. I keep getting the same error even after trying these simple fixes:

```
pip install --force-reinstall charset-normalizer==3.1.0
```

or

```
pip install -U --force-reinstall charset-normalizer
```

Comment: Hi @mitchcat, Have you installed conda environment? if yes, Please try by uninstall charset-normalizer using pip - `pip uninstall charset-normalizer` and again install using conda - `conda install -c conda-forge charset-normalizer`. Let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.